# Meteor Users collection vs additional collection

Tags: meteor

i'n trying to figure out, what's the best practice for building collections associated with user's data.(In terms of reactive, queries speed, or other.)
For example, what's better? 
Meteor.Users.profile: {friends, likes, previous orders, locations, favorites, etc"}.
Or create additional collection to keep this data, for example:
Meteor.UserInfo.user{friends, locations, previous orders, etc").
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Users collection to store information about that user that isn't related to other collections. Typically this should be at the top level of the user document, not inside the profile. The only thing I'd expect to see in the profile is profile information (and not, for instance, a list of previous orders).

Things like previous orders shouldn't be there since you can just query the Orders collection to find them. For performance reasons it *is* sometimes useful to denormalise this data, but this should be an exception, not the rule.

Comment: Thanks, so if I have a dashboard where I want to see all user's info, I will have to run queries to all collections with his Id. Doesn't it makes sense to keep on a collection (usersInfo) all the user's ref info, and query the collections directly with the ref ID? The other way around?

Comment: Denormalising data like that is hard work. Every time you add/remove an Order, for instance, you need to update the User too. The code is more complex, there more room for bugs. It's unnecessary. The only time this is justified is for performance enhancements, and for a dashboard that hardly seems necessary. You can always denormalise later if needed.

Comment: Got it. Calllbacks for each method is a hard and dangerous work. What about manipulating the Insert Id with the user's Id? _id: createdBy--uuid?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Obviously when you create an Order you'll add the ID of the user....

Comment: I meant create an order id that is built with two parts, where it's first part is built with the userId, instead of a random number. Again to make direct queries to the collection id, instead of searching for the createdBy in all the orders collection.

Comment: Absolutely not. There's no difference in search speed, just ensure that you have an index on the createdBy field.

Comment: related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919413/best-practice-for-nested-category-in-mongo-and-meteor